# Table cell uniformity

Tags: css

How do I get my table cells to have a uniform height and width regardless of what's in them?

I have a crossword puzzle where sometimes there's nothing in the cell, sometimes there's a letter, as the user completes a word, and sometimes there's a button in place of the letter after the word has been completed.

So I need every cell to be the same height and width (the width of a button that has a letter for its value).

Comment: Please show what you have tried. What is the HTML markup and the current CSS? Also please specify more exactly you want. Should the cells be square, with width and height equalling the width of a button with one letter? Then it seems that some JavaScript will be needed. (Note that the widths of such buttons may vary, by the width of letter, so you should specify the desired with in more detail, unless you use a monospace font.=

Comment: [Here it is](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Nibiru/XWord/XWord.cfm).  The answer to 1 across is: HOTSPOT.

Comment: The URL does not answer the question what exactly you want. *Which* uniform height and width? And as far as I can see, you are not using buttons at all but button-like rendering of elements via Bootstrap (for no good reason, I would say). Overall, the design looks unnecessarily complicated. But if you wish to keep using it, then you will need to specify the exact rendering you want, and someone needs to check out how to achieve that, given the framework you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
td{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Setting the width and height is enough, display: block; shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: if you put a big image inside the cell, it will adapt the image size regardless the width and height... try it out ;)

Comment: try display:inline-block instead of display:block;

Comment: I ultimately went with td { width:4.76%; height:57px;}